# Install OpenSnitch in Juno?

Tags: release-juno, software-installation, security

Has anyone managed to install [OpenSnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch) in Juno ?

I tried the install it using the procedure from the README.md, but the "make" command fails with the following error :

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ji2suxci/grpcio/
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `grpcio` in `ui/requirements.txt` first line. Delete it and `make` the project. Source code path: `$GOPATH//src/github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/ui`.

```
# grpcio==1.0.0
grpcio-tools==1.10.1
pyinotify==0.9.6
unicode_slugify==0.1.3
pyqt5==5.10.1
configparser==3.5.0
```